# Exercise 1.2.14 - Introduction to Mathematics of Medical Imaging (Charles L. Epstein)

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm currently working on an assignment in my calculus course where we have to prove the formula to calculate area D given in exercise 1.2.14 of the book Introduction to Mathematics of Medical Imaging by Charles L. Epstein. However hard I try to find possible proof of this formula, either it's doing it myself, asking people around me, or asking various AI assistants, I have yet to be successful at solving this problem. The assignment is due in 5 days so any help on this is highly appreciated. Thank you!!

Note: Depending on the edition it might be exercise 1.2.9 or 1.2.14

Link to the book: https://books.google.com.vn/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Mathematics_of_Medic.html?id=fErAEWU_sHUC&printsec=frontcover&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_entity&hl=en&gl=VN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Are we supposed to have that textbook at hand?

Comment: To get quicker attention, use the Do-My-Homework keyword. Best of luck!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! As the comments and downvotes indicate, you have to put in more effort in your question to attract answers. Please write down the problem and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please post a full statement of the question including explanations of the notation.

Comment: Make your post self-contained. No links making us do all your work. P.S. See Exercise 8d on p. 32 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.